# Mapping microarray probes

Tags: bioinformatics, bioconductor

I have analysed some microarray data that was floating around for a few years. I then noticed in the Limma output file that there were many probes which gene IDs were different from the gene IDs in any known database. I have managed to get the probe sequences from Agilent but I am having problems to assign them to genes in the genome. 
I do not have coordinates for the probes so I will need to map them first. Do you know any Bioconductor package that will take the probes in fasta format and output the genes where they are located using a gff file or gbk of the genome? I am working with *Acaryochloris marina*.

Comment: You could make a blast for each sequence and identify the gene that way. Take into account that the genomes are not definitive and what was mapped several years ago to a gene might be mapped to another place today.

Comment: Yes I end up doing it that wait and keeping the most significant hit, the problem were those probes that mapped to more than one spot.